# how to adjust the container as per the device screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

my app look like below

[image: this]

once logged in, in home page it has 3 tabs, and also a bottom navigation bar, and a app bar.

below the tab bar there is a container it contain many cards. I have given a fixed height to container, but when I checked in multiple devices there is a issue , i.e for the container having cards, getting overflow.

I tried to take the entire screen height then took the 70% for the container , but in phones with smaller resolution its showing overflow, if I adjusted as per that screen , In bigger screen , container takes very less space and more than 20% of space is wasted.

I am adding my code below,

here is my dashboard.dart code: ===>

```
import './generate_report_list.dart';
import './provider_classes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:bmnav/bmnav.dart' as bmnav;
import './dashboard_view.dart';

class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  Widget _view;
  double maxHeight;
  double maxWidth;
  double maxCardWidth;
  List<String> headers = ['Dashboard', 'Reports List', 'Profile', 'Settings'];
  List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.dashboard,
    Icons.insert_chart,
    Icons.account_circle,
    Icons.settings,
  ];
  List<String> images = [
    ('assets/dashboard.png'),
    ('assets/growth.png'),
    ('assets/user.png'),
    ('assets/settings.png'),
  ];

  getView(int index) {
    List<Widget> _viewList = <Widget>[
      GenerateReportList(),
      GenerateReportList(),
      GenerateReportList(),
      GenerateReportList(),
    ];

    setState(() {
      _view = _viewList[index];
      _currentIndex = index;
      Provider.of<ScreenHeader>(context)
          .setScreenHeader(headers[_currentIndex]);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String appBarHeader = Provider.of<ScreenHeader>(context).getScreenHeader();
    maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    maxCardWidth = maxWidth / 2;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            (appBarHeader ?? 'Dashboard'),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: _view ?? DashBoardView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: bmnav.BottomNav(
        onTap: (index) {
          getView(index);
        },
        labelStyle: bmnav.LabelStyle(visible: true),
        iconStyle:
            bmnav.IconStyle(color: Colors.black, onSelectColor: Colors.red),
        elevation: 10,
        items: [
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.home, label: 'Dashboard'),
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.trending_up, label: 'Reports'),
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.person, label: 'Profile'),
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.settings, label: 'Settings')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

generate_report_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

class GenerateReportList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GenerateReportListState createState() => _GenerateReportListState();
}

class _GenerateReportListState extends State<GenerateReportList>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future reportList;
  List<String> typesOfReports = [];
  String currentReportSummaryType;
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentReportSummaryType = 'detailed';
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  void _handleTabSelection(var index) {
    developer
        .log("index: array:" + typesOfReports[0] + "," + typesOfReports[1]);
    setState(() {
      print("index is " + index);
      if (index == 0) {
        currentReportSummaryType = "Group A";
      } else if (index == 1) {
        currentReportSummaryType = "Group B";
      } else if (index == 2) {
        currentReportSummaryType = "Group C";
      }
    });
  }

  getBody() {
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    developer.log('Max height:' + maxHeight.toString());
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: TabBar(
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  new Tab(text: 'Group A', icon: new Icon(Icons.list)),
                  new Tab(text: 'Group B', icon: new Icon(Icons.pie_chart)),
                  new Tab(text: 'Group C', icon: new Icon(Icons.insert_chart)),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
                onTap: _handleTabSelection,
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    height: (maxHeight * 0.60),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child:new Center(
                        child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        cardGen(),
                        cardGen(),
                        cardGen(),
                        cardGen(),
                        cardGen(),
                        cardGen(),
                      ],
                    )))))
          ],
        ));
  }

  cardGen() {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6) * 0.25,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("sample"),
                Text("dummy"),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  createCard(BuildContext context) {
    double maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    Container(
      height: (maxHeight * 0.6) * 0.25,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("sample"),
              Text("dummy"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getBody();
  }
}
```

provider_classes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenHeader with ChangeNotifier {
  String _screenHeader;

  getScreenHeader() => _screenHeader;

  setScreenHeader(String newHeader) {
    _screenHeader = newHeader;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

provider classes is just for displaying the data in appbar.

In dashboard.dart I am creating a appbar,and bottomsheet, and in generate_report_list I am adding 3 new tabs , for each tab once clicked I am displaying the cards.

How to assign the height to container carrying card so that it should fit on every device.,and how can I add scrollable to the tabs , i.e group A, group B, Group C.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        cardGen(),
        ...
```

To:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
        cardGen(),
          ...
```